# Issue with Read Character by Character of a String : JAVA

Tags: java

I have a very long String and I want to read character by character until the end of the String.

In Java, I found two ways to read it:

1. Using CharAt.
2. Using StringReader.

Can anybody help me:

1. Which one is the faster way ?
2. How to use StringReader to read character by character until the end
   of the String ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Measure it and find out! Seriously, things may be different for me on my hardware compared to you on your hardware. But I suspect `charAt()`
2. It's just a `Reader`, so it has the same methods as any other `Reader`, including `int read()` which will return you the Unicode code point for each character, one by one

Comment: Thanks. But why you suspect ? Is there any specific reason ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Measure it yourself. I can't see there being a meaningful/significant difference, once the string is loaded into memory.
2. [`StringReader#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29) (RFTD)

Answer (score 2):

How long is "very long?"

Convert the string to a char array using the toCharArray() method and have at it from a loop:

String mystring = "test";

char[] myCharArray = mystring.toCharArray();

Comment: That doesn't answer either question the OP asked.

Comment: He wants to "read character by character until the end of the string."

Comment: And then he says that in Java he found two ways to read it and I am offering him a third way that might work.

Comment: In case you need more convincing that I'm not trolling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672415/charat-or-substring-which-is-faster

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple class designed to do as you requested, with a charAt method:

```
public class Test {

static String tS = "Hello this is a string";


public static void main (String args []) {
//make a blank character that gets replaced each time the for loop runs     
char c;     
    for (int j = 0; j < tS.length(); j++) {
            //for loop runs up the length of the string, then sets c to the
            //current character in the string. Printing c just proves the concept.
        c = tS.charAt(j);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
}
```

Please remember that none of this needs to be done in a class or a main method - you could do it anywhere within your code that you needed it.