# Best way to get part of content from string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, memory, stringbuilder

I have a string like below

```
12SELVASOFTWAREENGINEER................323
```

This string length is more than `10000`

First two letter of this string is employee Id

So i can get my employee id like below

```
String empid = str.substring(0,2);
```

but this string creates the same space for original `String`, so memory leak will happen.

How to avoid this?

Is their any alternative or efficient way is their for getting the part of the string in java

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Does `String empid = new String(str.substring(0,2));` accomplish what you want?

Comment: Could you explain 'creates the same space for original string.so memory leak will happen'?

Comment: What memory leak are you talking about? 

`str.substring(0, 2)` returns a **new** string that is a substring of `str`. The new string will be only 2 characters long.

Comment: yes i agreed its creates new string but the allocated space for that string is  same as original string right?

Comment: The memory leak issue for `substring` was addressed in Java 7. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161050/java-string-substring-method-potential-memory-leak

Comment: @khelwood I am using java 1.7.Is it solved?

Comment: It was fixed in Java 7u6. If you are using any version after that (you probably are), then it isn't a problem. If not, do what @bradimus suggested.

Comment: @Khelwood,thanks for the solution.i am using jdk1.7.0_10 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but this string creates the same space for original string.so memory leak will happen.

I think you are referring to the behavior of `String` in older versions of Java where `String.substring(...)` created an object that shared the original `String` object's backing array.  As you point out, that *could* lead to a memory leak; e.g. if the original string became unreachable and the substring didn't.

The relevant code can be seen here:

- [`public String.substring(int, int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%2Cint%29)
- [`String(int, int, char[])`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%29)

**This problem was fixed in Java 7**.

Prior to Java 7, the standard workaround was to do something like this:

```
   String empid = new String(str.substring(0, 2));
```

(The `new String(...)` creates a string that does not share its backing array with either the original string or the substring.)

However, this is only advisable if:

- you are using an old release of Java,
- the original string is likely to be large, and
- the substring is likely to be long-lived.

Comment: ,thanks for the clear explanation about the substring method.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to keep in memory your original `String`, using `str.substring(0,2)` can still be used as it will only **reuse** the backing array of your original `String` so **it won't affect your memory footprint**.

However if you intend to get rid of your original `String` and want to consume less memory, then you could build a new `String` instance from the **first** (`charAt(0)`) and the **second** (`charAt(1)`) character of your original `String` as next:

```
String sub = new String(new char[]{s.charAt(0), s.charAt(1)});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly well:

```
String orig = "12SELVASOFTWAREENGINEER................323";

String empId = orig.substring(0, 2);
```

Why should there be a memory leak?

If you mean the memory that's held by orig, you can reset orig afterwards like so:

```
orig = null;
```

This will allow the long string to be collected by the garbage collector. 
The empId will still keep its value - in case you might fear that it gets cleared as well.