# What is the best way to get the first letter from a string in Java, returned as a string of length 1?

Tags: java, string

Assume the following:

```java
String example      = "something";
String firstLetter  = "";
```

Are there differences to be aware of with the following ways of assigning `firstLetter` that could impact performance; **which would be best, and why?**

```java
firstLetter = String.valueOf(example.charAt(0));
firstLetter = Character.toString(example.charAt(0));
firstLetter = example.substring(0, 1);
```

The reason the first letter is being returned as a `String` is that this is being run in Hadoop, and a string is required to assign to a `Text` type, `firstLetter` will be output as a `key` from a `map()` method, for example:

```java
public class FirstLetterMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    String line = new String();
    Text firstLetter = new Text();
    IntWritable wordLength = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        line = value.toString();

        for (String word : line.split("\\W+")){
            if (word.length() > 0) {

                // ---------------------------------------------
                // firstLetter assignment
                firstLetter.set(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)).toLowerCase());
                // ---------------------------------------------

                wordLength.set(word.length());
                context.write(firstLetter, wordLength);
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672415/charat-or-substring-which-is-faster

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Performance wise `substring(0, 1)` is better as found by following:

```
    String example = "something";
    String firstLetter  = "";

    long l=System.nanoTime();
    firstLetter = String.valueOf(example.charAt(0));
    System.out.println("String.valueOf: "+ (System.nanoTime()-l));

    l=System.nanoTime();
    firstLetter = Character.toString(example.charAt(0));
    System.out.println("Character.toString: "+ (System.nanoTime()-l));

    l=System.nanoTime();
    firstLetter = example.substring(0, 1);
    System.out.println("substring: "+ (System.nanoTime()-l));
```

**Output:**

```
String.valueOf: 38553
Character.toString: 30451
substring: 8660
```

Comment: This is way after the fact, but I feel like a more appropriate method of timing would involve performing this test many times, rather than once as implied by the code above. Please see my test code at gist.github.com/micahjsmith/c7c9d31b342c115aef90. Running Java 1.7 on GNU/Linux, I found no difference between the three methods as shown above, and if anything, String.valueOf had the best performance from what I saw. (Though there was some variation between runs.) This leads me inclined to believe that @yshavit below has a more applicable response to the question.

Answer (score 15):

Long story short, it probably doesn't matter. Use whichever you think looks nicest.

Longer answer, using Oracle's Java 7 JDK specifically, since this isn't defined at the JLS:

`String.valueOf` or `Character.toString` work the same way, so use whichever you feel looks nicer. In fact, `Character.toString` simply calls `String.valueOf` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Character.java#Character.toString%28char%29)).

So the question is, should you use one of those or `String.substring`. Here again it doesn't matter much. `String.substring` uses the original string's `char[]` and so allocates one object fewer than `String.valueOf`. This also prevents the original string from being GC'ed until the one-character string is available for GC (which can be a memory leak), but in your example, they'll both be available for GC after each iteration, so that doesn't matter. The allocation you save also doesn't matter -- a `char[1]` is cheap to allocate, and short-lived objects (as the one-char string will be) are cheap to GC, too.

If you have a large enough data set that the three are even measurable, `substring` will probably give a *slight* edge. Like, really slight. But that "if... measurable" contains the real key to this answer: why don't you just try all three and measure which one is fastest?

Answer (score 12):

```
String whole = "something";
String first = whole.substring(0, 1);
System.out.println(first);
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything, as this code is already proposed in the original question, and further extended in all answers to date.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1)
@Fork(value = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1)
public class StringFirstCharBenchmark {

    private String source;

    @Setup
    public void init() {
        source = "MALE";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String substring() {
        return source.substring(0, 1);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String indexOf() {
        return String.valueOf(source.indexOf(0));
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Benchmark                           Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| StringFirstCharBenchmark.indexOf    avgt    5  23.777 ? 5.788  ns/op |
| StringFirstCharBenchmark.substring  avgt    5  11.305 ? 1.411  ns/op |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -6):

```java
import java.io.*;
class Initials {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        char x;
        int l;
        System.out.print("Enter any sentence: ");
        s = br.readLine();
        s = " " + s; //adding a space infront of the inputted sentence or a name
        s = s.toUpperCase(); //converting the sentence into Upper Case (Capital Letters)
        l = s.length(); //finding the length of the sentence
        System.out.print("Output = ");

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            x = s.charAt(i); //taking out one character at a time from the sentence
            if (x == ' ') //if the character is a space, printing the next Character along with a fullstop
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i + 1) + ".");
        }
    }
}
```