# Get all hashtags from EditText

Tags: java, android, hashtag

I have an `EdiText`. User can mention hashtags in it. I want to get those hashtags and add them to an `ArrayList`. How can I get those hashtags from `EdiText`.

Suppose my `edittxtmsg` contains `#Stackoverflow slove me #hashtag #problem`

I want these hashtags: `#Stackoverflow #hashtag #problem`

```
edittxtmsg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    int strLenght = s.toString().length();
                    int available = 140 - strLenght;
                    setAvailableSpace(available);
                    if (available < 0) {
                        s.delete(strLenght - 1, strLenght);
                    }
                    mfinalmsg = s.toString();


                }

                private void setAvailableSpace(int available) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tvcount.setText(available + "");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Well, you have the text message and the hastag filters. You'd think there's a way to combine those two to get the info from the text? Linkify probably has no such methods because it wasn't intended to be used like that, though I am not very familiar with it. I'm sure there's an expert on here somewhere who can answer that.

Comment: anyother way to get hashtags mentions from edittext?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to get all hashtags from `EditText`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String text = editText.getText().toString();
String regexPattern = "(#\\w+)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    String hashtag = m.group(1);
    // Add hashtag to ArrayList
    ...
}
```

`(#\\w+)` matches all hashtags that start with `#`.

This one is also fast.

[image]

Comment: Thanks coder! if my edittext contains #### without spaces and text (tested). showing as a hashtag but not supposed be a hashtag ?

Comment: Then use `(#\\w+)` instead.

Comment: @Coder helping out fellow unsung heroes ;-) also found it cool that our method are equally fast/slow

Comment: if you have a hashtag that contains special characters like #hashtag-1 it will not pick up -1.. please help

Answer (score 5):

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
String[] words = text.split(" ");    
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( String word : words) {
    if (word.substring(0, 1).equals("#")) {
        tags.add(word);    
    }
}
```

Gets the text from `editText`, splits it into seperate words, creates a list of all words that start with #

As Yazan mentioned, a good alternative to `if (word.substring(0, 1).equals("#")` is `if (word.startsWith("#")`

Timing

[image]

Comment: just a question, is there an advantage for `substring()` over `startsWith()`?

Comment: @Yazan not sure, I read this topic that said substring was at least faster than the other 2 methods named there, but startsWith() is of course a good alternative. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201191/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-letter-from-a-string-in-java-returned-as

Comment: Thanks Tim! but i feel it is not the best way . it takes a lot time r8?

Comment: @SrikanthAppvolution no, this is quite fast actually

Comment: @SrikanthAppvolution I added a test run timing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63875/discussion-between-srikanth-appvolution-and-tim-castelijns).

Comment: This answer will pick up special characters in a word and thats important