# How to list all mentions in a String

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating an `EditText` that is possible to mention other users when writing @ with your nickname, like on Facebook, Instagram, Twitter etc. For example, in the text "Today @john and @jane ate a cake", I want to create an `ArrayList` with the values ​​"john" and "jane". [I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633544/9729980) but it didn't work. What to do to be able to do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Also, what are legal characters for the usernames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this Regex. It finds groups of word characters (letters, digits, underscores) that follow an @.

```
val atMentions: List<String> = "(?<=@)\\w+".toRegex().findAll(editText.text).map { it.value }
```

If you need to define a different set of word characters, replace the `\\w` above with `[\\w]` and put the other acceptable characters right after the w.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getMentionedNames(String text){
        String[] tmp=text.split("@");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=1;i<tmp.length;i++){
            String first=tmp[i].split(" ")[0];
            arrayList.add(first);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
if(text.contains("@"))
   text.split("@").forEach { list.add(it.substringBefore(" ")) }
```

Comment: This will greedily include any punctuation following a name, and it will include the first word in the String regardless of the presence of an @.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 good options for this:

1. Use regex and parse the fragment. Create groups of the found UserTags.
2. Use Apache UIMA Ruta to find structures in text and annotate the UserTags. https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html